# Accept PayPal payments using an unverified merchant account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm looking forward to use ***PayPal* Express Checkout for Digital Goods.** I'm using *PayPal* Business account.

When I was demonstrating in Sandbox, I was getting

> We are unable to complete your request at this time. Please try again
>   later paypal digital goods. We apologize for the inconvenience.

When I verified my *PayPal* sandbox account it works fine.

Now, for live version I want to use unverified *PayPal* account, since I'm not ready to be verified yet. I have a plan to be verified in future but not now. But I really need to integrate *PayPal* payment opt asap. Please let me know if there is any way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

No you must be verified by paypal in order to use a business account. There are many ways to verify and it should be a simple process taking no more then 2 days.